# Print piece of text using selenium with multiple open windows

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

With the help of the community I have been able to develop a piece of code that is able that prints the line of a webpage. However, I know want the code to print the piece of text for multiple webpages that match a certain xpath selector. How can this be done?

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()

matchpages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='preview-ico icon--preview']//*[name()='use']")
for matchpages in matchpages:
    matchpages.click()
    new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
    original_window = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.previewShowMore.showMore"))).click()
    main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='previewLine' and ./b[text()='Hot stat:']]").text
    main = main.replace('Hot stat:','')
    print(main)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(original_window)
```

I think the following line selects the first 'preview' page:

```
    new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
```

However, this then needs to be adjusted to all the 'preview' pages on flashscore.com.

Furthermore, the following lines should also be incorporated in the opened windows, as I would like to print out these lines in order to get a quick overview of the hot stats of that day.

```
main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='previewLine' and ./b[text()='Hot 
stat:']]").text
    main = main.replace('Hot stat:','')
    print(main)
```

Thanks in advance! : )

Comment: To clarify, you are looking to click on all the "preview" buttons, and extract the text from "hot stat" with each preview window popup?

Comment: @Ryan Burch Exactly! Preferably extracting them as a quick overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided was close. I ended up changing a few things, such as:

- Used webdriver manager instead of locally installed version
- Used service and options within webdriver.Chrome()
- Used XPATH for most of the elements

Code is below:
**NOTE that I had to click to the next day to get PREVIEW buttons to test, code is within two blocks, remove if needed**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/'
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()  # For maximizing window
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div[2]")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()
#  Put this Code in so I could test (clicks next so I had PREVIEW buttons to click)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]").click()
#
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div[2]")))

# Changed this to find all svg tags with the class of preview-ico icon--preview
matchpages = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='preview-ico icon--preview']/..")
# Loop through those elements found
for matchpages in matchpages:
    try:
        matchpages.click()
        # Switch to pop-up window
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[1]")))
        # click on the show more
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]").click()
        # get text of Hot stat element
        main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[6]").text
        main = main.replace('Hot stat:', '')
        print(main)
        # Scroll to close window and click it
        close = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Close window')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", close)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Close window')]").click()
        # Switch back to main window
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        # Handle timeout
    except TimeoutException:
        close = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Close window')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", close)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Close window')]").click()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        pass
    # Handle no element found
    except NoSuchElementException:
        close = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Close window')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", close)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Close window')]").click()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        pass
driver.quit()
```

**EDIT**
To handle possible Hot streak or Hot stat text field, please add an if/elif statement after finding the text field "main".

```py
main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[6]").text
if 'Hot stat:' in main:
    main = main.replace('Hot stat:', '')
elif 'Hot streak:' in main:
    main = main.replace('Hot streak:', '')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Burch, it is almost perfect.  As long as the hot stat is on the 6th 'paragraph' on the preview page it should work. Thanks!

Comment: I have on last question @Ryan Burch. Sometimes the full preview does not show a 'hot stat', but a 'hot streak'. Would it be possible to adjust this in the code, so in case that that only a hot streak is provided that this will be printed out instead of the Hot stat? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @error404 please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Would it also be possible to include this else statement in the CSS selector? main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='previewLine' and ./b[text()='Hot streak']]").text
main = main.replace('Hot streak','')
print(main). Sometimes the xpath selector does not seem to work for certain matches.